# how to modify my Logitech k810 special keys?

Tags: windows, keyboard, remapping

I downloaded SetPoint and remapped the special keys on my Logitech K810 keyboard.  However, the "my keyboard" tab there is not found.

I Googled and tried to reinstall and restart several times, turned on and off, but nothing happens.

I think the problem is that I am using an external Bluetooth 4 USB because my PC doesn't have Bluetooth, so it is defined as a generic Human Interface Device keyboard.  All I need to do is to replace the special keys "home and calculator" with "next/prev tracks".

Is there a way to fix this, or other methods to modify these keys?

I am on Windows 7 and tried many keyboard mappers, like KeyTweak and SharpKeys, but they don't support Logitech.

Comment: We'll not tell you another app because that is outside of the scope of SuperUser. We can help you find out why setpoint is not working, but for that we need more information.

Comment: Please [edit] the off-topic software request out of your question.

Comment: Hey, I downloaded setpoit and couldn't remap my special keys and that's the case! what is this edit? I didn't say that!!
we have been talking about editing the question rather than answering it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found a temporary solution on adding the media keys next/prev track:
for me I used an app like KeyTweak, I managed to remap the most two buttons I rarely use: the right ctrl and alt.
Explanation: with the "Half Teach Mode" in the program, when I press the special keys of logitech's calculator or home to remap, the app doesn't recognize them and it wont work that way, so instead, I used the most common keys like ctrl and alt that the any remapping app can recognize by default.